# run python script in current shell

Tags: bash

When I need to run a bash script that runs `cd somedir` to affect the current shell I run it with `. scriptname`. However, if `scriptname` is a python script even with `#!/usr/bin/env python3` in the first line, it doesn't work, it seems it expects the script to be a bash script. How can I make it work with python scripts (or any other language with the appropriate shebang)?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible.

The only thing that can affect current process environment is the process itself. Because the current shell is bash, the only thing that can be executed that could affect bash environment is something that can be run by bash itself. That "something" are statements interpreted by bash. Because bash doesn't support interpreting and running python statements, it is not possible.

The usual way around this, is to output from your python script properly escaped assignment statements that would assign environment variables. Then the output from your script is `eval`ulated by bash. This is for example how [`eval "$(docker-machine ...)"`](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/machine/get-started/#create-a-machine) works.